# What is the aerodynamic advantage to a cuffed wing like the Cirrus SR-22?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

What is the aerodynamic advantage to a cuffed wing like this Cirrus? [image: Cirrus SR-22]

Comment: I'm sure I read about how wings are designed to account for stalling at different times in this e-book, but skimming thru quickly I don't see it. <http://www.av8n.com/how/#contents>

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30921/1467

Comment: Related: [What does the zig-zag pattern on Hawker Hunter's leading edge represent?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2225/1696)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here we go:
http://whycirrus.com/engineering/stall-spin.aspx

> Spin Prevention
>   Cirrus chose, in the very earliest stages of designing
>   the SR20 to take on the challenge: to minimize the risks associated
>   with inadvertently stalling an airplane. The approach chosen was to
>   employ wing technology developed by NASA reducing the potential for
>   spin entry after an inadvertent stall. The most visible aspect is the
>   discontinuous leading edge dividing the wing into distinct parts.
>   ...
>   How does this wing design work?
>   The outboard section of the Cirrus wing flies with a lower angle of
>   attack than the inboard section. When the inboard section, which
>   produces much of the lift, stalls the outboard section, where the
>   ailerons are, is still flying. The result is that a stalled Cirrus
>   airplane can be controlled intuitively using aileron.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, nice find! It kind of makes me wonder why we don't see it on more designs though

Comment: Reading the page, it seems to appear on other more current designs as well.  I have micro-vortex generators on my plane that keep the airflow laminar in place longer with higher angle of attacks, keeps the airplane really responsive at low airspeeds and harder to stall.  <https://microaero.com/>  They work really well, help to really shorten & soften my landings.

Comment: Good luck to anyone that gets used to those handling characteristics when they next fly something that doesn't have this feature or lots of washout!

Comment: It's not hard to adapt.  I had to fly an old Cessna 172 for a BFR so I could move my vortex generator equipped Cessna 177 on a ferry flight for a long overdue annual inspection. I hadn't flown in 13  years.  The 172 was kind of doggy handling wise, compareed to the 177, and I had never flown one, but it was easy enough to stall it and recover, and the speed down final was similar.  I just couldn't let it get quite as slow as I would in the Cardinal.

Comment: @CrossRoads: Are you aware you keep posting broken links? It looks like you keep putting them in `<>` for some reason, and the `>` gets interpreted as part of the link.

Comment: @Geoff: It is a kludge that is slapped on a misbehaving wing after design. A better way is to design washout into the wing and to use different airfoils for the inner and outer wing. This step causes a jump in lift which is bad for induced drag. In short, the wing becomes less efficient in creating lift that way.

Comment: I thought <>  was what was used for links. What's the correct method?